# Conselho para guardar diversos arquivos no banco de dados

Tags: python, banco-de-dados, django

Estou fazendo um sistema utilizando Django e nele preciso guardar diversos documentos, eles podem ser com extensões de imagens, e tantas outras extensões, enfim são arquivos. Eu só estou com dúvidas em como eu guardo isso no banco. Eu vi alguns exemplos e notei que nele se guardava o endereço do arquivo no servidor, é essa a melhor forma de se tratar arquivos? ou eu posso guardar os arquivos diretamente no banco ao criar um modelo como exemplo abaixo:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    arquivo = models.FileField()
```

A questão então é, de que forma vale a pena eu guardar arquivos, tanto no banco de dados quanto no servidor.

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

O ideal seria usar um repositório de arquivos apropriado para guardar BLOB, como "amazon s3" ou "azure store blob".

E no banco SQL guardar o link do documento e o nome ou também pode usar um banco NoSQL, como MongoDB para arquivos menores que 16 megabytes e guardar os documentos no formato BSON (guarda em binário) e pode ser acessado por qualquer drive.

Ou para simplicar tudo, poderia usar um sistema distribuído como HDFS, diminuindo a manutenção e aumentando a escabilidade.
[Arquitetura HDFS](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HdfsDesign.html)
[Apache Hadoop no Amazon EMR](https://aws.amazon.com/pt/emr/features/hadoop/)

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Não seria mais vantajoso tornar a aplicação apenas um cliente dum sistema de arquivos distribuídos como [HDFS](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HdfsDesign.html) que por meio de conectores especializados pode se ligar a diversos sistemas e dispositivo de armazenamento, sejam clusters físicos ou remotos na intranet, vpn ou nuvem.  Evitando que o programa negociasse com as particularidades das diferentes APIs de armazenamento e comunicação de dados, obtendo um endereçamento de recursos uniforme e por consequência ajudando com manutenção e escalabilidade?

Comment: De fato! É uma boa alternativa!

Comment: @AugustoVasques nem precisa nada disso, se tiver um índice num banco relacional convencional - que é sensato para arquivos, afinal cada linha tem as mesmas colunas (dados ou endereço dos dados, nome do arquivo, data e demais metadados que sejam necessários para a aplicação) - pode apontar o source para infinitos servidores. Tem escalabilidade ilimitada e não precisa de nenhuma solução proprietária. O fechamento da pergunta tem a ver com isso, sem requisitos claros este tipo de pergunta vira um coletivo de "respostas de gosto pessoal". (comentei na resposta para o ping chegar no seu @ user)